Is there a single conduction band for all atoms in a crystal?
I'm a high school student studying the basics of semiconductors and have come across a diagram similar to this one:

What I understand from this is that a single electron (of a Silicon atom) would move from the valence band to the conduction band when provided with roughly 1.1 eV of energy. Would that not be true for the rest of the Si atoms as well?
Conduction bands, from what I've been told, are just outer energy levels and are virtually arising from valence shells. If I consider a part of the crystal (like in the diagram), and consider a row, wouldn't there be multiple conduction bands (and valence bands) for each row?

How does that explain the concept of 'free' electrons or the fact that in P-type semiconductors, the acceptor level of a Boron atom is at a lower energy level than the conduction band?
I'm sorry if this comes off as silly but I can't seem to find a definite answer for this question.

Well, those sketches are to give you a bit of insight, but they are nowhere near what real solid state physics does.

The energy bands don't have a location in space. Drawing them like that does not make any sense. They are intervals of allowed energies not intervals of allowed positions in space. They "belong" to the whole crystal.

@nasu Wrong.The bands are for certain positions of the crystal.If that was the case in case of a p-n junction , we would need to draw the donor and acceptor levels both across the crystal which isnt true.Also if there is a irregularity in some specific position the bands bend there.

The OP is talking about a homogeneous crystal. And even for a p-n junction, the energy bands ar still bands in the energy space and not in the real space. They don't have location in space. It's just that the energy bands of the structure are different at different locations.
